# "rails activestorage:update" errors out while upgrading to rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am performing an upgrade in rails version from 5.2.3 to 6.0.0 in our application and ended up with the following error when I run `rails app:update` and accept default changes.

```
Overwrite /Users/pk064816/solemnity/bin/setup? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdhm] y
       force  bin/setup
   identical  bin/yarn
       rails  active_storage:update
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rule_monger-0.3.0/lib/rule_monger.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant HOST_PORT
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/netapp_oncommand_rest-0.2.1/lib/netapp_oncommand_rest.rb:21: warning: previous definition of HOST_PORT was here
rails aborted!
NameError: wrong constant name [[:error, ["detected unsupported rails version 6.0.0"], nil]]
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.7.0.350/lib/new_relic/control/class_methods.rb:52:in `const_get'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.7.0.350/lib/new_relic/control/class_methods.rb:52:in `load_framework_class'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.7.0.350/lib/new_relic/control/class_methods.rb:32:in `new_instance'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.7.0.350/lib/new_relic/control/class_methods.rb:13:in `instance'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.7.0.350/lib/newrelic_rpm.rb:41:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
/Users/pk064816/ClosedStack/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:515:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/Users/pk064816/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => active_storage:update => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

After this, check Rails upgrade guide at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html for more details about upgrading your app.
```

I do not really make use of `activestorage` inside the application and any configs specific to `activestorage` are only the defaults obtained from rails 5.2.3.

Here's what I have in my `bin/rails`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  load File.expand_path("../spring", __FILE__)
rescue LoadError
end
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

and in `bin/setup`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'fileutils'

# path to your application root.
APP_ROOT = File.expand_path('..', __dir__)

def system!(*args)
  system(*args) || abort("\n== Command #{args} failed ==")
end

FileUtils.chdir APP_ROOT do
  # This script is a way to setup or update your development environment automatically.
  # This script is idempotent, so that you can run it at anytime and get an expectable outcome.
  # Add necessary setup steps to this file.

  puts '== Installing dependencies =='
  system! 'gem install bundler --conservative'
  system('bundle check') || system!('bundle install')

  # Install JavaScript dependencies
  # system('bin/yarn')

  # puts "\n== Copying sample files =="
  # unless File.exist?('config/database.yml')
  #   FileUtils.cp 'config/database.yml.sample', 'config/database.yml'
  # end

  puts "\n== Preparing database =="
  system! 'bin/rails db:prepare'

  puts "\n== Removing old logs and tempfiles =="
  system! 'bin/rails log:clear tmp:clear'

  puts "\n== Restarting application server =="
  system! 'bin/rails restart'
end
```

and `config/application.rb`

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Solemnity
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Use Resque for our Active::Jobs
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :resque

    # Add lib to autoload path
    config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
    config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    config.exceptions_app = self.routes
  end
end
```

I tried to disable the use of `activestorage`, but that didn't really work! I am not entirely sure what's causing an error here and would really appreciate any help in working around this problem!

Comment: Have you tried upgrading new_relic?

Comment: Yes like @MarkMerritt says: either upgrade or (my suggestion) temporarily remove new relic.